# How to bin the summarised frequency table with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
  select(distance) %>% 
  group_by(distance) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(distance) %>% ungroup() 

df
#> # A tibble: 214 x 2
#>    distance     n
#>       <dbl> <int>
#>  1       17     1
#>  2       80    49
#>  3       94   976
#>  4       96   607
#>  5      116   443
#>  6      143   439
#>  7      160   376
#>  8      169   545
#>  9      173   221
#> 10      184  5504
#> # … with 204 more rows
```

What I want to do is to bin the `distance` column by bin of size 100,
and also summing the `n` column accordingly.
How can do that?

So you get something like:

```
bin_distance sum_n
1-100       1633  #(1 + 49 + 976 + 607)
101-200     21344 # (443 + ... + 5327)
#etc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most simple approach would be to use `cut` by creating `groups` using `seq` for every 100 values and `sum` the values for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = cut(distance, breaks = seq(0, max(distance), 100))) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n))


#   group         n
#   <fct>       <int>
# 1 (0,100]      1633
# 2 (100,200]   21344
# 3 (200,300]   28310
# 4 (300,400]    7748
# 5 (400,500]   21292
# 6 (500,600]   26815
# 7 (600,700]    7846
# 8 (700,800]   48904
# 9 (800,900]    7574
#10 (900,1e+03] 18205
# ... with 17 more rows
```

---

which can be translated to base R using `aggregate` like

```
aggregate(n ~ distance, 
 transform(df, distance = cut(distance, breaks = seq(0, max(distance), 100))), sum)
```

Answer (score 6):

A different `tidyverse` solution. It is closely following the logic of @Ronak Shah code, but instead of `cut()` it uses `cut_width()` from `ggplot2`:

```
nycflights13::flights %>%
 select(distance) %>%
 group_by(ints = cut_width(distance, width = 100, boundary = 0)) %>%
 summarise(n = n())

   ints            n
   <fct>       <int>
 1 [0,100]      1633
 2 (100,200]   21344
 3 (200,300]   28310
 4 (300,400]    7748
 5 (400,500]   21292
 6 (500,600]   26815
 7 (600,700]    7846
 8 (700,800]   48904
 9 (800,900]    7574
10 (900,1e+03] 18205
```